# Paypal batch settlement programmatically

Tags: java, paypal

I am trying to figure out if we can do programmatic batch settlment? I am looking for a process where I can generate a CSV file and get it settled instead of firing capture settlement in a loop for all the authorizations that has happened over the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although it's not a feature that's advertised and it has to be enabled on your account by a PayPal agent.  If you open a ticket at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com and ask for Batch Capture to be enabled on your account, we can get you the specs on it.  (If you include the ticket number in the comments, I can reply back to you personally.)

Comment: Great. Thanks. Here is the reference number of the ticket  `160526-000212`. This forum is great.